# Why isn't my program accessing the superclass' array as expected?

Tags: java, arrays, class, variables, applet

I searched for an answer to this problem for quite some time, and I have done a lot of different tests, and I have narrowed and simplified a bug in my Java Applet down to this small piece of code. I am guessing that this exact same bug would come up if it was not an Applet though.

Here is the Main class.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Main extends Applet{

  public int[] a = {2};
  public int[] b = new int[1];

  public void init(){
    b[0] = 4;
    Otherclass s = new Otherclass();
  }
}
```

Here is the Otherclass.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Otherclass extends Main{

  public Otherclass(){
    System.out.println(super.a[0]);
    System.out.println(super.b[0]);
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
2
4
```

Actual Output:

```
2
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Micah

Comment: It makes no sense for a parent class to hold variables to child classes. It's bordering on insane actually. Why do you have this?

Comment: @everybody: this is an applet, `init()` is called by the browser. Nevertheless, this is a complete misunderstanding of how inheritance works.

Comment: @moonwtave99: amen. Again the code is just crazy.

Comment: It is for a tower defense game, and I have a Main, Enemy, Tower, and Bullet classes. And since Enemy and Tower are both subclasses of Main, and I have an array "t" for the Tower objects, and an array "e" for the enemy objects, I need the Tower to be able to access the array "e" so that it knows where the enemies are and is able to aim at them.

Comment: That's just it -- none of those clases should subclass your Main class, and to do so is to mis-use inheritance. If you're doing this to allow the subclasses access to shared variables, then you're going to have serious problems. I strongly suggest that you re-design your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have created the instance of Otherclass, it is a diffrerent instance to your Main instance. So b[0] = 4 in the Main instance, but is not initialised in the Otherclass instance.

You see the same value of a[0] because that is initialised with the class.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `super.` prefix

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. The question, then, would be how do I access the array which is actually in the Main class instead of the one initialized in the instance of OtherClass? Because the array in the Main class needs to be constantly changing!

Comment: You ARE accessing the array in the main class. `Otherclass` does not have its own arrays, it inherits them from `Main`. But, if I understand you correctly, you want to see the same values of the arrays from all instances of `Main` and `Otherclass`, so declare them as `static`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm marking your answer as correct! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `b` in the constructor of `Otherclass` - which will be executed before the `Applet` launcher gets to execute `init`.

If you put this statement:

```
b[0] = 4;
```

into the constructor of `Main`, it will be executed before the constructor body of `Otherclass`.

Note that your initialization of `s` in `init` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have never actually initialized that array in the instance of OtherClass you have just created.  When the instance of OtherClass is created, that snippet of code that you have in Main init() method:

```
b[0] = 4;
```

Is never executed for the OtherClass instance b array, which is an **entirely different variable in memory** than the b array that exists for the Main class instance.  That is the reason you don't see that '4' in the array

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. The question, then, would be how do I access the array which is actually in the Main class instead of the one initialized in the instance of OtherClass? Because the array in the Main class needs to be constantly changing!

Comment: If you need to share that information between both objects, then inheritance is not the answer, because it multiplies the instances of the b array in every object you create.  Try composition instead - just make a getter method for the array in Main class and access it through a reference to the object, or just leave it static in Main class.

Comment: I added these two getters to the Main event: `code` public int[] getArrA(){return a;} public int[] getArrB(){return b;} `/code` and changed the other class to `code` int[] aa = super.getArrA(); int[] bb = super.getArrB(); System.out.println(aa[0]); System.out.println(bb[0]); `/code` and it still didn't work! Same output!

Comment: Ok, but remember that you must call these methods through a reference to the Main class instance, or you will find the same problem as before

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression that that's what "super." did. Since the Otherclass is the child, or subclass, of the Main.

Comment: "super" just calls a method definition done in the superclass... but referring to the same instance of the object.  In your case it brings you to round the same problem until you discard the idea of inheritance and get to a composition solution

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will have to research the idea of composition then, and then find a way to use it in my program. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You are welcome, these are tricky problems when you start with an OO language.  Have fun with java!!! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but @NickJ provided me with the exact answer I was looking for. All I needed to do was declare the arrays as static! I tried that with my original program and it worked perfectly!